# give user full rights on a list via powershell

Tags: powershell, splist

I have messed up my rights on a list, so I can still view it, but cannot edit it. I need full permissions on it again.

Is there a way to set my admin account back to full rights via powershell?

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a sledgehammer to crack a nut.  Do you have anybody with Site Collection Admin permissions that can reset them for you?  In fact, if you have access to run PowerShell then you can almost certainly make yourself a Site Collection Admin.

Comment: I am the SiteCollection administrator. But the inheritance is broken. I cant access the permissions.

Comment: That should not make any difference to a Site Collection Admin?

Comment: Well kiss my f... a.... One of my co-admins removed my sitecollection admin status, for whatever reason. 
After CA came up I just set myself to SC admin again. this is clearly not what In want to do on a friday, but I guess it is time to go kill someone.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. +1